# "I never went to poker yesterday" - Is this grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, past-tense

A colleague of mine often pulls me up on my awful grammar, earlier today I said "**I never went to poker yesterday**" and she told me that it was grammatically incorrect.

I understand that I *could/should* have said "**I did not go to poker yesterday**" but I would like to know whether my original statement was technically a grammatically correct statement, because in my head it makes logical sense.

Thanks

Comment: Grammatical, yes, but not in the standard dialect(s).

Comment: Works better if "poker" is actually a contraction.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd I hardly even know 'er!

Comment: How many times did you go to poker yesterday?  I never went to poker yesterday!

Answer (score 5):

The other answers are all incomplete. In many parts of England

> I never went to poker last night

is perfectly normal (except that the people who speak that dialect probably don't play much poker).

For many British speakers, *never went* with a specific time mentionedor implied is the normal way of expressing standard *didn't go*, perhaps with a slight intensification of meaning.

And, as I said in a comment, it is normal to use the name of an activity (without an article) as a pseudo-place, meaning "my regular attendance at". *At swimming*, *after salsa*, *on the way to choir*, *during rehearsal*, *instead of bridge*, are examples.

Comment: There are some instances where the definite article is preferred: 'went to the racing' (often 'races', of course); 'went to the dancing'; even 'went to the jazz on Sunday' (I've heard the last expression, but there's only one Google hit). 'Went to the opera' is probably count-noun rather than activity usage.

Comment: Dropping the verb *play* must be a colloquial ellipsis more common in the UK than in the US.

Comment: "Never went" meaning "didn't go" is a common expression to me in the U.S. as well, but it sometimes conveys (with more emphasis than "didn't go") a sense of emotional interest in the fact, such as disappointment, disapproval, contempt, regret or surprise. Situational context would determine what sense it is used.

Comment: And you can separate the main verb (whether it's "went" or something else). So, "I never" means "I didn't" in the context of a particular time period. "Did you play poker last night?". "No, I never". The response means "not last night", it doesn't suggest the responder hasn't ever played poker on any night.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: it's not dropping the verb _play_; it's abbreviating the noun phrase _the poker session_ or _our regular poker game_ or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean: "I was intending to go play poker yesterday, but for some reason I never got around to it", then yes, your sentence is all right. But it might be better to say: "I never did go to poker yesterday", with stress on "did".

Comment: _Never ... did ... yesterday_ does not sound correct. It might be used by some speakers but it does not sound correct in my ears.

Comment: @mplungjan: It's perfectly ordinary English. Here are a couple of written instances of [*"I never did see him last night"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22never+did+see+him+last%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), for example. In such contexts, ***never did*** is simply an "intensifying" alternative to ***didn't***, and it's not generally considered to be a "flaky" usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *never* used as an intensifier sounds very British to me, although I can't figure out a way of testing whether this is right using Ngrams.

Comment: @Peter: I wouldn't have thought it's particularly *British* to say *"I'd **never** have thought this is a specifically BrE usage"*. But I do have a sense that the more extreme form *"I never said that"* (in contexts where the scope of "never" is simply my last contribution to an ongoing conversation) is probably more BrE than AmE.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Right. *"I'd never have"* is perfectly fine in AmE. But certain uses of *never* restricted to a time period, like *"I never saw him last night"*, sound British to me. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @Peter: It seems to me *"I never saw him last night"* is a *less* "extreme" usage, since you could interpret it as *"At no point in the entire evening did I see him"*. What I'd call the "extreme" version would be something like *"I never watched University Challenge last night"* in the "pre-Tivo" era (when you could *only* have watched it or not *at the time it was broadcast)*. Which makes it the same as my example *"I never said that"*, where *never* is really just an intensifier with no particular connotations of *not at any time*, since the actual time is explicit (or very implicit)

Answer (score 2):

There are two items at issue:

1. *"to poker"* v.s. *"to play poker"*
2. *"never went"* v.s. *"did not go"*

Unless *poker* is a physical location, like the library, you should use *"to play poker"*

Both *"never went"* and *"did not go"* imply that you did not travel somewhere to play poker yesterday.

The phrase *"never went"* might also imply that you intended to play yesterday.

**EDIT#1**

As Colin points out, there are some places where the phrase *"to poker"* is common.  This is a **regional colloquial ellipsis** in which words are removed and assumed to be there.  In Bradford Pennsylvania, I could say *"The car needs washed."* Most listeners would assume I meant *"The car needs to be washed.*

The decision to use this type of phrase depends on the rules you are trying to follow.

Comment: In this context, I view "poker" less as a verb and more as and event/place. Along the lines of "I never went to (summer) camp as a child"

Comment: "Poker" can be short for "poker night" or "the poker game". It's not necessarily "play poker". It's similar to how one might ask, "How was soccer [practice]?"

Comment: @JohnKugelman **I agree with you,** but it's just a different ellipsis.  To you *"I never went to poker."* may mean *"I never went to the poker game."*  The ambiguity to me is attending an event versus going to play!

Answer (score 0):

Poker is a game not a place.  You go to a location and went refers to location.  Since poker is not a location it would sound awkward at best saying you went to it.  It would be on par with saying I went to Monopoly last night.  Huh?

So you can say - "I never went to the poker game last night" or "I didn't play poker last night".

Comment: This reply is correct for some more formal registers of English. It is quite wrong for colloquial British usage (and I suspect other Englishes as well). Talking about going to poker, to football, to judo, to swimming are all perfectly normal here, and imply that this is a regular appointment.

Comment: I go *"to the movies"* and not *"to the movie theatre"*. Why can't I go *"to poker"* and not *"to the poker game"*?

Comment: @ColinFine - I completely agree but people you are talking to are assuming that you are going to [play] poker, football [league], judo [practice].  It depends on the context of both speaker and listener.

Comment: @PeterShor - because in your area movie theatre has been shortened to "the movies".

Comment: @RyeBread: Not completely; I can go to the movie theatre ***without*** going to the movies (although why I would want to ...)

Comment: At least you aren't playing deadly games, like [chess](http://www.theguardian.com/sport/2014/aug/15/deaths-world-chess-olympiad-norway).

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd: how do you know what people you are talking to are assuming? In any case, it's irrelevant: you said (or implied) that you can't say "to poker last night", and I disagree. What that might or might not be expandable to is irrelevant.